# XML DTD - xPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT db (obj, prop*)>
<!ELEMENT obj (obj*)>
<!ATTLIST obj
    id ID #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT prop (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST prop
    objs IDREFS #REQUIRED
>
```

I need to write a xPath, which return all "prop"s, where "objs" contains of "obj"s with children.
For example:

```
<db>
    <obj id="a007">
    <obj id="a008"> </obj>
        <obj id="a009">
            <obj id="a011"> </obj>
        </obj>
    </obj>   
    <obj id="a011"> </obj>
    <prop objs="a007 a011">
        "first"
    </prop>
    <prop objs="a007">
        "second"
    </prop>
    <prop objs="a009 a007">
        "third"
    </prop>
</db>
```

a want it return second and third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the path `/db/prop[not(id(@objs)[not(obj)])]`, it selects those `prop` element child nodes of the `db` root element where `id(@objs)` does not find an element not having an `obj` child.